# Alt+Shift doesn't change keyboard language on Ubuntu Kylin

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kylin

I want to change keyboard language with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on Ubuntu Kylin, but this doesn't change the language.

My input keyboards are English,Indian:

[image: Screenshot from language options]

Comment: Have you tried `Super key + Space` ?

Comment: @David: Ubuntu Kylin is an official Ubuntu flavor.

Answer (score 0):

The input method configuration window you show is the Fcitx one. Assuming you have Fcitx configured (you can check that via the *Language Support* tool), the default Fcitx shortcut for switching input source is Ctrl+Shift. You can change that in the *Global Config* tab.

Answer (score 0):

As Gunna said, you seem to be using `fcitx`.  By default, Fcitx use `Ctrl Space` to change keyboard layout and `Ctrl L/R Shift` to change input methods.  So if you haven't changed the default shortcuts, you can just use these ways.

By the way, the UKUI desktop environment provides an entry point for quick toggles, you can find a keyboard icon on the panel and clicking it will cycle through the available keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and then a reboot to change the shortcut.

Source: https://vitux.com/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu/